# Google maps not loading properly

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I will lead with the image:

[image]

This is what is returned when I create my google maps embed with the API.

My JS

```
var map;

    function initMap(){
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('maphere'), {
          center: {lat: -81.378373, lng: 28.536156},
          zoom: 18
        });
    }
```

my HTML:

```
<div id="hideMapOverflow">
     <div id="maphere" style="height:100%"></div>
</div>
```

And the CSS that goes with it:

```
#hideMapOverflow{
    overflow:hidden;
    height:500px;
    width:100%;
}
#maphere{
    height:100%;
}
```

The maps component seems to load, but the map itself isn't. Did I miss anything?

Comment: Where's the HTML? Please provide a full example of your code/html that recreates the image you have.

Comment: It looks like you're hitting Antarctica: https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/81%C2%B022'42.1%22S+28%C2%B032'10.2%22E/@-81.3783611,28.533978,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0

Comment: And you're zoomed waaay in. Try sane coordinates/zoom level

Comment: This is my first time... What's considered a "sane" zoom level?

Comment: Strangely enough, I'm not able to scroll about

Comment: Hey, thanks Stackoverflow for down voting... I actually found the answer. The browser window width was actually too small for it to render (for some reason). So I need to make sure that the map is loading within the parent's width or else it wont load completely...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your latitude and longitude are backwards.

```js
var map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('maphere'), {
    center: {
      lng: -81.378373,
      lat: 28.536156
    },
    zoom: 18
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
#hideMapOverflow {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
#maphere {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="hideMapOverflow">
  <div id="maphere" style="height:100%"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would like to also add that the width of the map (on my phone) didn't allow it to load, you know why that is?

Comment: No.  It works fine on my (Android) phone (at least the code snippet in my answer  does, don't know about your "live" page, you didn't provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: Can you run Chrome on your iPhone?  Does it work in that?